Vite build project and widgets into separate bundles
I need your help/advice on how to configure Rollup in Vite the right way to produce the desired build bundles.
I already have an up-and-running Vite config which builds the Vue project.
Part of config is
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: {
          mapboxGl: ['mapbox-gl']
        }
      }
    },

    sourcemap: 'hidden',
  },

  plugins: [
    vue(),
    svgLoader()
  ],

The project structure is simple ->
.
├── index.html
├── public
├── src/
│   ├── main.ts
│   └── components/
│       └── ... *.vue and ts files
└── ...

I have added folder widgets to src where will live standalone widgets.
I want to get in the dist folder separately builder bundles like:
.
└── dist/
    ├── index.html
    ├── assets/
    │   └── ...everything related to the project
    └── widgets/
        └── every widgets folder with built bundle + CSS

Currently, I have the result without widgets folder.
I have experimented a bit with rollupOptions and got this config:
 build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        index: fileURLToPath(new URL('src/main.ts', import.meta.url)),
        ...Object.fromEntries(
            globSync('src/widgets/**/*.ts').map(file => [
              // This remove `src/` as well as the file extension from each
              // file, so e.g. src/nested/foo.js becomes nested/foo
              relative(
                  'src',
                  file.slice(0, file.length - extname(file).length)
              ),
              // This expands the relative paths to absolute paths, so e.g.
              // src/nested/foo becomes /project/src/nested/foo.js
              fileURLToPath(new URL(file, import.meta.url))
            ])
        ),
      },
      output: {
        manualChunks: {
          mapboxGl: ['mapbox-gl']
        }
      }
    },

    sourcemap: 'hidden',
  },

  plugins: [
    vue(),
    svgLoader()
  ],

Unfortunately, this config doesn't produce index.html into dist folder for main project, and /widgets folder is added into the main project's /assets folder.
Please help to achieve
.
└── dist/
    ├── index.html
    ├── assets/
    │   └── ...everything related to the project
    └── widgets/
        └── every widgets folder with built bundle + CSS

Thank you

Does this answer your question? How can I customize the output filename when multiple inputs in rollup.js?

@AlexanderNenashev partially. It helped me to separate build bundles (move widgets to right place), but index.html file is still missing. It should also have included generated bundle (this is how it is is done when not putting anything into inputs)

i guess you should select index.html as an input, not main.ts
